# Limit Azure Function restart rate

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I already faced similar problem few times:
Azure Function with ServiceBusTrigger by some reason (misconfiguration, infrastructure issues, doesn't really matter) fails to connect to ServiceBus (so it happens on trigger level) and it leads to two issues:

1. It tries to restart all the time, increasing CPU consumption
2. It generates literally a millions of exceptions in AppInsights, which leads to quota exceedance
   Practically every error in configuration means significantly increased bills and requires thorough monitoring after every deployment, which is annoying and error prone solution.

So, my question: If there is a way to set some delay between restart attempts to (for example) one second? And, as addition - is there way to limit amount of restart attempts and then shut down the Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establishing a connection to the broker to fetch messages is Functions responsibility, Scale Controller. That aspect is entirely abstracted from customers and not configurable. I suggest raising an issue with [Azure Functions](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions) team, likely under the [Runtime repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20sort%3Aupdated-desc).